# Leiningen - how to kill the child process?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When I launch a webapp with `lein run` or `lein ring server`, I get two processes: Leiningen itself, and my app. When I terminate the session with Ctrl+C, it terminates Leiningen and leaves my app running.

How can I terminate both processes or prevent Leiningen from spawning a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/455 This issue is fixed on the Leiningen master branch, and also is backported to the 1.x series as 1.7.1.

Comment: I saw some of the mailing list conversation on Cygwin, they aren't sure yet how to fix it.  How are you running in Eclipse @Konrad?  Currently, I use Leiningen to generate a pom file and use CounterClockwise and m2eclipse to run and repl/manage dependencies.

Comment: I use Eclipse with CCW, but run Leiningen as "external tool". I get the same behavior in this case (spawns process that does not get killed when I terminate). Looks like launching the app with CCW and booting my app in REPL may be the best way around for now...

Answer (score 1):

What about running `lein repl` and then start the server by calling your `main` function from the REPL.